# validating xml file with dtd using jsp

Tags: xml, jsp, dtd, validating

Is there any way to validate an XML file with its DTD, using a JSP in Eclipse? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: Do you mean programmatically validate a file when running inside the container, or validate an XML file in Eclipse?

Comment: its verification of xml document based on the given structure(i.e., DTD)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

1. Specify the DTD at the top of the jsp, as if it is a regular XML document;
2. `right-click the jsp > Validate`.